# Laravel string is not entering/updating in the database

Tags: php, laravel

First is it checks if request form has the same username in the database and then the first name that is saved in the database to be compared with the request form. But it is not entering in the database I may have done something wrong when turning the strings into arrays or using the for loop to compare both strings but I can't spot the error can you help me?

```
if (User::where('username', $request->username)->exists()) {//check if request form has the same username in the database

    //first name that is saved in the database to be compared with the request form
    $fnameSavedInDatabase = DB::select('select first_name from users where username = ? and first_name != ?', [$request->username, $request->first_name]);

    //turn into array
    $fnameSavedInDatabaseArray = str_split($fnameSavedInDatabase);

    //request form value turn in to an array
    $fnameIncomingArray = str_split($request->first_name);

    //value that will be saved/updated in the database
    $fnameFinalIncomingString;

    for ($index = 0; $index < strlen($request->first_name); $index++) {
        if ($fnameIncomingArray[$index] == $fnameSavedInDatabaseArray[$index]) {
            $fnameFinalIncomingString = $fnameFinalIncomingString . $fnameIncomingArray[$index];
        }
    }

    $user = User::create($request->all());

    $user->update(['role_id' => $request->role]);
    $user->save();
    $user->update(['username' => $fnameFinalIncomingString]);
    $user->save();

    $roleName = $user->role()->name;

    return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'roleName' => $roleName, 'manager_exists' => '0']);
}
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the string to compare them?

Comment: im using for a username generator, the gist is that if the database has an existing username it will add the oncoming username letter by letter as long as those two split strings are the same each letter it will stop when they have a difference. $fnameSavedInDatabase is the existing fname when same username triggers $fnameIncomingArray is the request form on submit.

Comment: So, I'm guessing you want the username to be case sensitive?

Comment: I forgot to add that the username is based on firstname and lastname so the format is [flastname], what I was trying to solve is that what if Alejo Santos and Allan Santos will have the same username of asantos. If Allan Santos tries to register he will have a username of alsantos when it detects that asantos is already taken. And so on.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case I'm assuming that the 2nd username would then be `alsantos`? If so, what happens when you get to a point where all of those usernames have been taken i.e. you end up with a username like `allansantos`? I would suggest implementing something that either appends the id of the user to the username or having an additional table to check how many times that username has been taken (assuming that a user can't then change their username).

Comment: You're right I should just append the id to "_"id rather than what I am having right now with my unneeded complexity. should just be asantos_id for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your model User.
It has to have in

```
protected $fillable = ['username',....]
```

then in your dev envirenoment using tinker debug updating username without mess you have.

in cmd

```
php artisan tinker
```

Then

```
$user = \App\User::find(1);
$user->update(['username' => 'mytestname']);
```